# Rails 3 - automatic AJAX request

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, rendering

I am struggling with a problem about automatic AJAX load of page. I have normal static page, where is a link. After click on this link I will call an AJAX request for loading a data.

This works me. I try now to add next functionality - I would like after load a normal static page to load that AJAX data automatically - is possible to do somehow?
I tried it to do whole afternoon, but I still don't know, how to do it...

So, I will very grateful for every hints, how to do it... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your Ajax call in your [jQuery ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function, e.g.:

```html
<script>
  $(function() {
    $.ajax(...);
  });
</script>
```